# How do I update the costmap origin's orientation with the help of static layer plugin in Nav2?

Tags: costmap, nav2

I have been trying to use the static layer plugin in Nav2. My custom map_topic has a different orientation of its origin as compared to the /map topic published by slam toolbox. But the processMap function in the static layer plugin only changes the costmap origin's position. How do I change the origin's orientation wrt to my custom map_topic? Is there a parameter for this that I might have missed?? And what is the default orientation and position of the origin??? Any response in this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map's orientation is not used and should be aligned with the generated map (or reorient you SLAM map). Rotations are not used by the map server since grid-based mapping techniques cannot have their maps arbitrarily rotated without aliasing the pixels. Though, you can do this yourself easily with any kind of graphics editing tools and is very commonplace.